# How to Sort a list for a specific case c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

here is a sample code where i want get sorted data on TotalCharge property in desending order like this way.

```
//List<RateStatus> SortedList =  objListOrder.OrderByDescending(o=>o.TotalCharge).ToList();
```

see my below code and guide me how to sort TotalCharge property in desending. thanks

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            List<RateStatus> oRateCollection = new List<RateStatus>();
            RateStatus oRateStatus = new RateStatus();

            oRateStatus.StatusMsg = "Ok";
            oRateStatus.ErrorMsg = "None";
            oRateStatus.RateDetails.Add(new RateDetails()
            {
                CurrentcyCode = "GBP",
                TotalCharge = 20

            });

            oRateCollection.Add(oRateStatus);

           // i want something like this below
           //List<RateStatus> SortedList =  objListOrder.OrderByDescending(o=>o.TotalCharge).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class RateStatus
    {
        public RateStatus()
        {
            RateDetails = new List<RateDetails>();
        }

        public string StatusMsg
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ErrorMsg
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<RateDetails> RateDetails
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class RateDetails
    {
        public string ServiceCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ServiceName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CurrentcyCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double TotalCharge
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

### This way it has been sorted.

```
oRateStatus.RateDetails.Sort(new RateStatusComparer());
oRateCollection.Add(oRateStatus);


public class RateStatusComparer : IComparer<RateDetails>
    {
        public int Compare(RateDetails x, RateDetails y)
        {
            if (x.TotalCharge > y.TotalCharge) return -1;
            else if (x.TotalCharge < y.TotalCharge) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Why `RateDetails` is a List? Does that mean multiple items can exist? If so how do you want to sort?

Comment: please guide me how to sort data based TotalCharge property in descending order.

Comment: So you want to sort the `oRateCollection` list or the `RateDetails` property of the list?

Comment: want to sort oRateCollection based on  TotalCharge property in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that implements `IComparer<RateStatus>`.

For example, something like this:

```
public class RateStatusComparer: IComparer<RateStatus>
{
    public int Compare(RateStatus x, RateStatus y)
    {
        ... your comparing code here
    }
}
```

And then you can use overload of `List.Sort` and provide your comparer like

```
var с = new RateStatusComparer();
objListOrder.Sort(c);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s) for details.

Comment: Just write appropriate comparison logic in `RateStatusComparer`. Something like: if x.RateDetails.Sum(r => r.TotalCharge) > y.RateDetails.Sum(r => r.TotalCharge) then return -1, if equals then 0 else 1. This will ensure descending order or sum(totalCharge).

Comment: @Andy Korneyev : i solved the issue after following your approach. thanks

Comment: @Andy Korneyev: you use sum() like sum(totalCharge). but without sum() i solved it. will mind to explain why you said to use sum(0 function ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code

Since Total charge is a numeric value, we can use Min and Max methods for sorting.

Descending:

```
List<RateStatus> SortedList = oRateCollection.OrderByDescending(o => o.RateDetails.Max(r => r.TotalCharge)).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry it did not work. i check SortedList and i saw haphazard data was coming. not sorted at all.

Comment: I added the below list to your existing code and my sorted list instance ordered by 25,20,5. `RateStatus oRateStatus2 = new RateStatus();
            oRateStatus2.RateDetails.Add(new RateDetails()
            {
                TotalCharge = 5
            });
            oRateCollection.Add(oRateStatus2);
            RateStatus oRateStatus3 = new RateStatus();
            oRateStatus3.RateDetails.Add(new RateDetails()
            {
                TotalCharge = 25
            });
            oRateCollection.Add(oRateStatus3);`